# Stream with Node.js doesn't work

Tags: http, streaming, node.js, browser

I know that with Node.js you can stream data.

But why doesn't this code work:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write("hello");
    res.write("world");
}).listen(80);
```

Seems that I have to have res.end() after the last res.write() to be able to send the data to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems more like the output has to be a certain size before the browser renders it. Probably the buffer at the browser end. When you send `res.end()` the browser flushes this buffer and renders all that's in the buffer straightaway. However, if no `res.end()` is send, the browser awaits till its buffer is filled.

I tried experimenting the following block of code with Firefox and curl.

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write("hello\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        res.write("world lotsa text here lotsa text\n");
      }, 400*i);
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

You can try it yourself by heading to http://localhost:3000/ after running node with the above code.

I then tried the same thing with curl, and every line appeared straightaway as it was sent from the server.

The curl command I used was simply:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/
```

Note the newlines I inserted in the res.write as curl will wait for the newlines before outputting to stdout.

Answer (score 2):

I think the chunk has to be a certain size before it's sent.